# how to make nav bar disappear unless icon clicked?

Tags: html, css

This is my first question. Sorry if it is not very clear. I am trying to make a website that is compatible with mobile devices. I made a nav bar exclusively for mobile devices with menu icon and close icon. I only want the nav bar to show when clicked on but it stays on the website messing with the presentation. Here's the code.

```css
.nav-links ul li{
  display:block;
}

.nav-links{
   position:absolute;
   background:beige;
   height:100vh;
   width:200px;
   top:0;
   right:-300px;
   text-align:left;
   z-index: 2;
   transition: 1s;
}

 nav .fa-solid{
   display:block;
   color:black;
   margin:10px;
   font-size: 22px;
   cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<section class="header">
   <nav>
     <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
       <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
       <li><a href="">SERVICES</a></li>
       <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
       <li><a href="">POLICIES</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <i class="fa-solid fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
   </nav>
</section>
```

Comment: I forgot to add that I do have @media(max-width:700px){ as my header on the css code

Answer (score 0):

I took the event handler out of the markup and put it in the js. When you click the trigger to open the menu, the menu slides out by adding the class "open-nav". The trigger to open the menu also gets hidden when this happens. When you click the trigger to close the menu, the menu slides away again and the trigger to open the menu reappears.

```js
const navLinks = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
const openTrigger = document.querySelector(".fa-bars");
const closeTrigger = document.querySelector(".fa-xmark");

const handleMenuOpen = () => {
  if ( !navLinks.classList.contains("open-nav") ) {
    navLinks.classList.add("open-nav");
    openTrigger.classList.add("hide-trigger");
  }
}

const handleMenuClose = () => {
  if ( navLinks.classList.contains("open-nav") ) {
    navLinks.classList.remove("open-nav");
    openTrigger.classList.remove("hide-trigger");
  }
}

openTrigger.addEventListener("click", handleMenuOpen);
closeTrigger.addEventListener("click", handleMenuClose);
```

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.nav-links ul li{
  display:block;
}
.nav-links {
 position:absolute;
 background:beige;
 height:100vh;
 width:200px;
 top:0;
 right:-300px;
 text-align:left;
 z-index: 2;
 transition: 1s;
}
 nav .fa-solid{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 color:black;
 margin:10px;
 cursor:pointer;
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
 border: 3px solid black;
}

.nav-links.open-nav {
  right: 0;
}

.fa-bars.hide-trigger {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="header">
     <nav>
       <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
         <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark">X</i>
         <ul>
           <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
           <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
           <li><a href="">SERVICES</a></li>
           <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
           <li><a href="">POLICIES</a></li>
         </ul>
       </div>
       <i class="fa-solid fa-bars">+</i>
     </nav>
   </section>
```